# Is there a standard practice for splitting packages into modular components?

Tags: go

I'm working on a library with multiple layers of functionality. I want developers to be able to import only the parts they need, ie `mylib-core`, `mylib-feature1`, `mylib-feature2`, etc. Each lives in its own git repo. I'd also like to provide a simple `mylib` package which exposes a default set of functionality which is useful for developers new to the library. See [d3.js](https://github.com/d3) version 4+ for something very similar to what I'm trying to accomplish.

The problems I've run into are

1. Apparently you can't share a package name between packages. This is a problem because it would be nice to import all the desired repos and then simply have everything available under the `mylib` name.
2. I don't see an obvious way to re-export functionality, in order to build the default `mylib` package.

Are there good solutions or a more idomatic go way to accomplish what I'm shooting for?

Comment: Why do you want to expose all of your functionality from one package? That pretty much defeats the purpose. I would strongly consider just exposing multiple clearly-defined packages and letting developers use them like packages. Go developers are used to the package-per-feature model.

Comment: It wouldn't be the end of the world if it comes to that. I think the bigger problem is having to come up with short names (no underscores or camelCase) that are still meaningful for each package, even though semantically I don't see any problem with them sharing a single `mylib` name. I think it's confusing for users of the lib

Comment: If the functionality belongs together from the importers point of view, then use one package.

Comment: But the packages represent distinct functionality which could be used on its on, and shouldn't require them to download and build everything else in order to use

Comment: Then they absolutely should be separate packages with distinct names appropriate to the functionality they expose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering your question, there is no **idiomatic** way of doing what you want. It is common in JavaScript to import a library and export its members without interference. This is not the case in Golang.

I advise you to host your whole library under a single repo, and split the functionality to packages. The Go compiler will only compile and use the imported packages.

And a tip for the future, Go is very different than almost any other language you previously know